# URIError: URI malformed em NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, lado-do-servidor

Código server-side

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 8080;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use((req, res, next)=>{
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,content-type");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    next();
});
app.post("/api", (req, res)=>{
    res.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
    res.set("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
        const msgData = {
            getMsg : req.body.phrase,
            geMsgDUC : decodeURIComponent(req.body.phrase),
        };
        console.log(JSON.stringify(msgData));
        res.send(JSON.stringify(msgData.geMsgDUC));
});
app.listen(port, (err)=>{
    if (err){
        throw err;
    }
    console.log("Server started on http://localhost:"+port);
});
```

Requisição no Client-Side

```
fetch("http://localhost:8080/api", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, 
    body: "phrase="+encodeURIComponent("~(+´g°i.v=+[ÿqéºqiyk'ïìù;7ú´=%dz")
}).then(function(response){
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(json){
    console.log(json); 
  });
```

estou tendo um erro como retorno no lado do servidor:

```
URIError: URI malformed
at decodeURIComponent (<anonymous>).
```

OBS: a string é encodada e decodada normalmente no no console do browser.

Comment: Você leu qual foi o erro? O servidor devolveu para o cliente o que foi que aconteceu.

Comment: li sim amigo, estou iniciando com js do lado do servidor, poderia me explicar o porque desse erro? ja que no lado do cliente(browser) não acontece?

Comment: [Leia no mdn sobre o erro que lhe aparece](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Malformed_URI). No seu caso alguma informação a ser codificada não está valida

Comment: eu ja li amigo, a 3 dias atrás, e vale lembrar que esse erro só acontece no server-side, se eu encodar a informação no lado do cliente tudo ocorre normalmente entendeu?